# how would I print a pattern then print the reverse pattern next to that pattern?

Tags: java

Hey how would I print a pattern then print the reverse pattern next to that pattern? like this:

```
1            1 2 3 4 5
1 2          1 2 3 4
1 2 3        1 2 3
1 2 3 4      1 2 
1 2 3 4 5    1
```

I know how to print both the patterns I just can't find out how to print the second pattern next to the first one.

```
package exc3;
public class Exc3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int row = 1;
        int i = 0;

            for (i=1; i<=row; i++){
                System.out.print(i + " ");

                if (i == row){
                    System.out.println();
                    i = 0;
                    row++;
                }

                if (row > 5)
                    break;

            }

    }
```

that's the code I have for making the pattern but I don't think I need help with that just with putting the second pattern next to the first I have no idea how to do that

Comment: What have you tried so far? At least post some code of what you have tried!

Comment: If you don't print a newline after the first pattern, the second pattern would be in the same line.

Comment: I wonder why printing triangles comes up so often as a question. Is this part of some course?

Comment: it's part of just about every programming 1 course, and sorry if this question has been asked before I tried looking it up but I could only find on print 1 pattern. not both patterns next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that you want!!

```
import java.io.*;
public class Exc3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int row = 1;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int max = 5;
        for (i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" ");

            if (i == row) {
                for (j = 1; j <= max; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
                for (j = 1; j <= max; j++) {
                    System.out.print(j + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                i = 0;
                row++;
                max--;
            }
            if (row > 5)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
1           1 2 3 4 5 
1 2         1 2 3 4 
1 2 3       1 2 3 
1 2 3 4     1 2 
1 2 3 4 5   1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @Inzinity .Consider accepting the answer if your problem is solved!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider it as one pattern.

triangle of numbers as well as blank space. And you have to print whole line and then only you can go to next line (`System.out.print(i + " ");`). If you print 1st triangle, there is no way you can move last triangle from down to up.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the code, but the some hints and link to help you learn.

You should first of all know how long the string can be. You can then generate two strings, one for the first part of each line and one for the second.

A this point you can use [`String.Format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) using the right padding [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)